# SNMP: How to monitor devices that do not have static IP adress with Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, snmp, dynamic-ip, zabbix

I have some equipments in my LAN but the way things are working; I cannot set statics IPs for them, they really need to have DHCP enabled.

I am using Zabbix, and for host configuration, the IP address is required; is there any way to go around this ?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a scenario where equipment *must* have a dynamically assigned IP address. Even if you can't set a device to use a static IP, if you have control of the DHCP server, can't you just have it assign it a "static" IP that you will know (DHCP reservation)?

Answer (score 0):

Install agent in your client as a active
In active agent connect to server and used hostname for detect on zabbix server.

[zabbix-agent-active vs passive](https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-agent-active-vs-passive/9207/)

Answer (score -1):

Zabbix requires an "Interface", not an "IP address". Using the DNS name solves the problem, provided of course that the environment is correctly configured, ie. your DHCP updates the DNS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1029200)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: your comment is in line with the memes, and you should not be proud of this. Your comment does not add anything to the discussion, is not on topic with the question, and does not help solving the original issue. The problem is: Zabbix requires an "Interface", not an "IP address" as the OP thought. Using the DNS name solves the problem, provided of course that the environment is correctly configured.

Comment: If you'd included that information, minus the snark, instead of the ellipses, you'd have a good answer and we wouldn't be having this conversation. The good news for you is that there's a very useful EDIT button you can click to add that information, and then you WILL have a good answer and not just a comment.